# javascript - Complete call first before success part in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a jQuery code to download file and after download file must delete from server. Below is my code for file download and delete file.

```
if (method == "ValueAddedReportExportToExcel") {                
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("ValueAddedReportExportToExcel", "report")',
        data: {
            fromDate: $('#txtFromDate').val(),
            toDate: $('#txtToDate').val(),
            reportForWhom: $("#ddlReportForWhom").val(),
            customers: (ddlCustomers != null) ? ddlCustomers.join(',') : "",
            salesReps: (salesReps != null) ? salesReps.join(',') : "",
            users: (users != null) ? users.join(',') : "",
            emailTo: emailTo,
            subject: subject,
            body: body,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            fileName = data.fileName;

            // call to download action.           
            window.location = '@Url.Action("Download", "Report")' + '?file=' + data.fileName;
            console.log('Success Call');
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log('Complete Call');
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "post",
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Report")',
                data: { file: filename },
                success: function () {
                    alert(filename + ' is deleted successfuly. ');
                }
            });
        }
    });
    //methodURL = '@Url.Action("ValueAddedReportExportToExcel", "report")';
}
```

And below two functions are for download and delete function in controller.

```
public virtual ActionResult Download(string file)
{
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CostSavingReport"), file);
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
    //return File(fileBytes, "application/vnd.ms-excel", file);
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, file);
}

public virtual void DeleteFile(string file)
{
    try
    {
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CostSavingReport"), file);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Now the problem is first `DeleteFile` action is called instead of `Download` action what to do to make call first to `Download` and after it `DeleteFile`.

Comment: Delete it server side.

Comment: And after that, what should i do? @SergeK.

Comment: Move the deletion part inside the `Download` function if you want to remove the file once it's downloaded. Otherwise you rely on the client who can leave the page once the download is over and the delete code would never be called whatever is you solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create custom attribute for that action like below that executes after your method is been executed

```
public class DeleteFileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
{ 
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) 
    { 
        // Delete file 
    } 
}
```

and use it over your action

```
[DeleteFileAttribute]
public virtual ActionResult Download(string file)
{
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CostSavingReport"), file);
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
    //return File(fileBytes, "application/vnd.ms-excel", file);
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, file);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but not so familiar with ActionFilters, can you throws some light where to write file delete code? either in DeleteFile or  OnActionExecuted?

Comment: you have to write your delete code in "public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) " method and this method is going to call right after download finishes execution.

Comment: @wacky_coder you could refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx for more reference

Comment: Thank you!! This action filter worked for me. many thanks. (y)